# Community changes valid links to invalid

Tags: discussion

Community edited [my question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251286/questions-that-have-more-upvotes-than-views) and changed valid links to invalid, and left strange comment.
[image: Community's edit image]

Is there any reason for it?

Comment: Can you point at any post that is still currently like that? Community user fixed those back.

Comment: [My.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251286/questions-that-have-more-upvotes-than-views)

Comment: @Oded It seems like Community user is changing the links to point to MSE even though the target posts have been migrated back to MSO.

Comment: @Antony - yes, this was reported on [MSO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251770/community-user-incorrectly-changing-links-from-mso-to-mse). The script was not discriminating.